# Using phrase matcher on a large scale to alter tokenization

Tags: spacy, cjk

I am a beginner to the spaCy system.

Take this example-

```
好きになる
```

The tokenizer and tagger on the pretrained Japanese models would likely give the output `好き` (noun) `に` (adp) `なる` (aux). While this is correct, it doesn't take into consideration that this whole expression is a figure of speech, which I'd be interested in for my project's purposes. I also want to make it so that no matter what the 'conjugation' of the input is, that the output is able to match.

A kind user on the forum has already suggested this solution (has a different example)

```
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

ja = spacy.load('ja_core_news_sm')

pattern = [{'LEMMA': '気'}, {'LEMMA': 'に'}, {'LEMMA': 'なる'}]

matcher = Matcher(ja.vocab)
matcher.add("kininaru", None, pattern)

for text in ('あの子が気になる', 'あれが気になった'):
    doc = ja(text)
    matches = matcher(doc)
    _, start, finish = matches[0]
    print(doc[start:finish])
```

With an output of :

```
気になる, 気になっ
```

Now, if I wanted an output of all the tokens in the sentence, they also suggested to simply merge entities.

Now, here's where I am a little confused. This example: "[Pipeline component for entity matching and tagging with custom attributes](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#component-example2)" seems a lot longer, but I am not sure what extra is being done. It also seems that the example that someone provided me, as opposed to the Spacy example, modifies the output of the morphemizer and tokenizer after calculations. But the spacy example actually uses the rules when calculating (becomes part of the model). Is my understanding correct, and if so, what would I do if I have a dictionary of 10 000 or so expressions I want to incorporate? Here is an example of what I'm looking for.

```
parse("あなたは手も足も出ないんだぞ")
[("あなた", PRONOUN), ("は", PARTICLE), ("手も足も出ない", EXPRESSION), ("んだ" EXPRESSION), ("ぞ" PARTICLE)]
```

as opposed to spacy's output of

```
あなた(pronoun) は(adp) 手(noun) も(adp) 足(noun) も(adp) 出(verb) ない(aux) ん(sconj) だ(aux) ぞ(part)
```